# React Shorthand for passing state in component render

Tags: reactjs

As we know that React.Component render can be called like this

```
render ({props},{state}){
    //logic goes here
}
```

consider if we have some states named a,b,c,d so we can call the render method like this

```
render ({props},{a,b,c,d}){
        //logic goes here
}
```

so imagine if we have so many states, can us do some shorthand like this?

```
render ({props},{this.state}){
        //logic goes here
   console.log(a,b,c,d,e,..,z)
}
```

or is there any other best practice?

Comment: Their [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) makes no mention of this for class components.  Class use render but do not provide arguments. Function components only use props and not state. Where exactly did you see this convention? Would you mind providing an example of this?

Comment: actually i'm using preact, but after researching i think it would be same approach with react, in react it would similiar like this https://medium.com/@jonatan_salas/using-linkstate-in-your-react-components-to-simplify-event-handlers-9d157cb75082

Comment: so the problem is how to shorthand the writing of those variables, let say we have state = {a:1,b:2,c:3} how to acces a directly

Comment: Uhm, did you wanna do const `{a,b,c} = this.state` inside render function? That’d give you a,b,c as short vars.

Comment: @PredragBeocanin yes, but imagine if my state is so many, it's not fun to write {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,} = this.state